# How to find out with which user gvfs has connected to smb share

Tags: gnome, smb, gvfs

I can connect to network drives with the following command:

```
( echo myusername; echo MYDOMAIN; echo password123 ) | gio mount smb://127.0.0.1/Sharename
```

And I can get some file attributes of the mount point:

```
gio info smb://127.0.0.1/Sharename

Anzeigename: Sharenameauf 127.0.0.1
Name bearbeiten: /
Name: /
Typ: directory
Größe:  0
Adresse: smb://127.0.0.1/Sharename/
Attribute:
  standard::type: 2
  standard::name: /
  standard::display-name: Sharename auf 127.0.0.1
  standard::edit-name: /
  standard::icon: folder-remote, folder-remote-symbolic
  standard::content-type: inode/directory
  standard::size: 0
  standard::allocated-size: 0
  standard::symbolic-icon: folder-remote-symbolic, folder-remote
  etag::value: 0
  id::filesystem: smb-share:server=127.0.0.1,share=Sharename
  access::can-trash: FALSE
  time::modified: 0
  time::modified-usec: 0
  time::access: 0
  time::access-usec: 0
  time::changed: 0
  time::changed-usec: 0
  unix::device: 2648392497
  unix::inode: 6160419607250089214
```

But how can I fetch the name of the user that connected to the share ("myusername" in the case above)?